# Google Adsense is displaying wrong size ad in header

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense

I'm new to google adsense. Earlier I designed one website in **Wordpress** and put google adsense code( page-level-adsense code) in my my site.

From last week, I'm getting very strange issue. **Google Adsense(page-level-adsense)** is displaying wrong size of advertise in my site header means vertical ad(Size of Ad is 219*600) is showing at horizontal place. so my site structure is being distorter.

My Website is : https://liveascoder.tk/

**Note**: If I visit my site first time then it will work fine but after refresh the page my site structure is being distorter because of wrong size ad.

Eralier I was using Google Adsense plugin so position was fixed for ad but now official adsense plugin is no more for wordpress so i unable to fix postion. Anyone can solve out my problem please?

**Update1**: I fixed this issue using ad unit but if i put page-level-adsense code then again facing same problem. Anyway for now I'm using ad unit code and fixed position of ad also.

Comment: I fixed this issue using ad unit but if i put page-level-adsense code then again facing same problem.....Anyway for now I'm using ad unit code and fixed position of ad also.